# Generate classes from values using dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

For example, I have the list of values in a column: `10, 20, 30, 40, 50` and I want to get in another column something that looks like `10-20, 30-40, 40-50`.

Please how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want. I'm assuming that given a list of values you want strings representing the ranges from each value to the next higher value.

```
# This is what you have
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

# This adds the column you want
df = df.sort_values('val')
df['class'] = df['val'].astype(str) + '-' + df['val'].astype(str).shift(-1)
```

I'm not sure how you would want to handle duplicate values. You might want to add this before creating the `class` column.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```